# Use MouseEvent for getting Object`s public variables

Tags: actionscript-3, class, mouseevent, mouse, target

I have a simple problem which is not easy at the moment. this is a text field class which add a text field to a movieclip (passed from root class) and also save(buffer) some data (like xml file name) in it`s public variables:

```
package src {
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
public class menuitem00 extends Shape {
    public var activateFlag:Boolean = false;
    public var name00:String = "";
    public var xml00:String = "";
    public var txt00:TextField = new TextField();

    private var OM:MovieClip;
    private var id00:Number = 0;

    public function menuitem00(n:int ,OE:MovieClip ,xmlf:String):void {
        trace (" Text Field Object with buffer ");
        OM = OE;    id00 = n;   xml00 = xmlf;
    }
    public function init():void{
        // textfield

        txt00.selectable = false;
        txt00.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        txt00.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Impact", 36,0x66AAFF);
        txt00.text = name00;
        txt00.border = true;
        txt00.borderColor = 0x00FF00;
        txt00.sharpness = 100;
        txt00.x = 0;
        txt00.y = (id00 * txt00.height) + 1;
        txt00.z = 0;
        OM.addChild(txt00);
    }
}
```

}
 .. now I use a for loop to add instance of that class to a movie clip on stage:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<Bunker[0]["trans0size"]; i++) {
    menuData[i] = new menuitem00(i, menu_mc, Bunker[0]["transfile0" + i]);// pass i , a movieclip named menu_mc and an xml file name 
    menuData[i].name00 = Bunker[0]["transtitle0" + i]; // pass text 
    menuData[i].activateFlag = true; // set actveFlag to true
    menuData[i].init(); // run init() inside the instance. it adds textfield to the menu_mc and also set name00 as Text for the textField
}
```

also I add mouse event for clicking on the stage,

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clk, false, 0, true);
public function clk(evt:MouseEvent):void{   //// mouse 
    trace (" Name: " + evt.target.text);
    //trace (evt.target.xml00);
    }
```

HERE IS MY PROBLEM --> I want to get "xml00" var from that instance on the stage by mouse click but, `trace (evt.target.xml00);` is not working .. also `trace (evt.target.name00);` is not working. I can get everything like `.alpha` or `.text` from `txt00` but not other variables in my object. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

don't add the click-listener to the STAGE but to you object.

```
menuData[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clk, ...);
```

and add the following line to your menuitem00 class:

```
this.mouseChildren = false;
```

so you can be sure that the evt.target is an object of this class and not a child (like the textfield or something else).

**edit**

if you want to keep the stage-listener, try this:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clk, ...);

private function clk (evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (evt.currentTarget is menuitem00)
  {
    var item:menuitem00 = evt.currentTarget as menuitem00;
    trace(item.xml00);  // or any other public variable 
  }
}
```

but still add the `mouseChildren = false;` to your class.

**edit2**

make the menuitem00 class a sprite (and rename it pls):

```
public class MenuItem extends Sprite {
  private var _activateFlag:Boolean;
  private var _xml:String;
  private var _txt:TextField;
  private var _id:Number;

  public function MenuItem (n:int, xmlf:String) {
    trace (" Text Field Object with buffer ");
    _id = n;
    _xml = xmlf;
    _activeFlag = true;

    this.mouseChildren = false;

    // create txt
    _txt = new TextField();
    // do the formating here ...
    this.addChild(_txt);
  }

  public function getXml():String {
    return _xml;
  }
}
```

in the for loop you would do sth like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<Bunker[0]["trans0size"]; i++) {
  var item:MenuItem = new MenuItem(i, Bunker[0]["transfile0" + i]);
  item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clk, false, 0, true);
  menu_mc.addChild(item);
  menuData[i] = item;
}

private function clk (evt:MouseEvent):void {
  var item:MenuItem = evt.target as MenuItem;
  if (item != null) {
    trace(item.getXml());  // use a getter and don't access the variable directly
  }
}
```

and pls re-read your actionscript (or programming) books, you're doing some really bad things i your code that you shouldn't.

Comment: he could also add the event listener to the stage like he has, and use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

Comment: .. it works fine .. : ) ,, .. but, I have 400 - 600 instances on stage and 400 - 600 mouse  event is not good .. any other method ?

Comment: I try `trace (evt.target.parent.parent.menuData[0].activateFlag);` and it shows me `menuData[i].activateFlag` which is `true` .. but I can not get the answer yet .. : \ ,,

Comment: i just saw why it is not working ... because your is neither a sprite nor a movieclip and doesn't contain the textfield but just creates is and adds it to the MC that you passed from the Main class. bad practice! make the class extend sprite and don't pass the MC but create an object from the class and add the new textfield directly to the instance with `this.addChild(txt);` edited answer to include what i just wrote.

Comment: Thanks ! ... I remove the movie clip from the class and use `this.addChild(txt);` method which is really better .. I end up with `for (var i:int = 0; i<Bunker[0]["trans0size"]; i++) {
 menuData[i] = new menuitem00(i, Bunker[0]["transfile0" + i]);
 menuData[i].name00 = Bunker[0]["transtitle0" + i];
 menuData[i].activateFlag = false;
 menuData[i].init();
 menu_mc.addChild(menuData[i]);
} and use `item.getXml()` and everything work fine ... I have a problem with getXml(), it is already a "function" and I want to access `xml00` from `evt.target` in more direct form. Is that possible ?

Comment: Because, if I use `trace(evt.target.parent.parent.menuData[0].activateFlag);` it return `true` which means. I can access all public variable in my root from that mouse event... so I want to access all public var of that class with same way ... I don know how . .. : \

Comment: you should never use anything that is as crude as this: evt.target.parent.parent.menuData[0] ! this just has to break ! clean up the code/class and everything should work fine.

Comment: Why not?!!  That is fast, instead of using a `function` and extra variables and `if` statement, I can directly access to the class public variables (if possible)... anyone know any solution?